# DjangoRestFramework: Unit Testing AssertionError: 404 != 200 while Test update

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've started writing unit tests for my API's but am stuck while updating user details received an assertion error of 404!=200. I'm sharing mycode for the reference.
Please do let me know my mistake and a brief explanation as I'm new to django rest.

I've created only one class "class TestUser(APITestCase):" for testing 2 API is it fine as I'm extending the URL in the update client patch?

```
models.py

mport email
from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser)

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'male'),
    (1, 'female'),
    (2, 'not specified'),)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
  def create_user(self, email, name,contact_number,gender,address,state,city,country,pincode,dob ,password=None, password2=None):
      """
      Creates and saves a User with the given email, name and password.
      """
      if not email:
          raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

      user = self.model(
          email=self.normalize_email(email),
          name=name,
          contact_number=contact_number,
          gender=gender,
          address=address,
          state=state,
          city=city,
          country=country,
          pincode=pincode,
          dob=dob,
          
      )

      user.set_password(password)
      
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user

  def create_superuser(self, email, name,contact_number,gender,address,state,city,country,pincode,dob , password=None):
      """
      Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, name and password.
      """
      user = self.create_user(
          email,
          
          name=name,
          contact_number=contact_number,
          gender=gender,
          address=address,
          state=state,
          city=city,
          country=country,
          pincode=pincode,
          dob=dob,
          password=password,
          
      )
      user.is_admin = True
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',max_length=255,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_number= models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pincode= models.IntegerField()
    dob = models.DateField(null= True)


    # is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','contact_number','gender','address','state','city','country','pincode','dob']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

```
views.py

class UserListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsUserOrIsAdmin]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        if self.request.user.is_staff == False:

            user_data= self.request.user.id
            data = User.objects.filter(id= user_data)
            return data
        else:
            data = User.objects.all()
            return data

    
    
    
class UserRetrtieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsUserOrIsAdmin]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        if self.request.user.is_staff == False:

            user_data= self.request.user.id
            data = User.objects.filter(id= user_data)
            return data
        else:
            data = User.objects.all()
            return data
```

```
urls.py

path('customer_info/', UserListCreateAPIView.as_view()),
    path('customer_info/<int:pk>/', UserRetrtieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view()),
```

```
tests.py

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from .models import User







class TestUser(APITestCase):
    url = "/api/v1/customer_info/"

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create(email="naveen@example.com",name="Naveen",contact_number="9090909098",gender="0",address="jaipur",state="Rajasthan",city="Jaipur",country="India",pincode="302016",dob="1907-07-20",is_active="True",
        is_admin= "False")

    def test_get_User(self):

        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        print(response)
        result = response.json()
        # print(result)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIsInstance(result, list)
        

    def test_post_User(self):
        # definition
        data = {
            "email":"ujjval@example.com",
            "password":"123456",
            "name":"ujjval",
            "contact_number":"9090909098",
            "gender":"0",
            "address":"jaipur",
            "state":"Rajasthan",
            "city":"Jaipur",
            "country":"India",
            "pincode":"302016",
            "dob":"1907-07-20"
        }

        # process
        response = self.client.post(self.url, data=data)
        # print(response)
        result = response.json()
        # print(result)

        # assert
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        self.assertEqual(result["email"], "ujjval@example.com")

    def test_update_User(self):
        pk = "1"
        data = {
            "email":"naveen@example.com",
            
        }

        response = self.client.patch(self.url + f"{pk}/", data=data)
        result = response.json()
        print(result)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(result["email"], "ujjval@example.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the names of the URL paths and use them in the test class.

```
path('customer_info/', UserListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name="customer_info_view"),
path('customer_info/<int:pk>/', UserRetrtieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name="customer_info_detail_view"),
```

And in the test class,

```
from django.urls import reverse

class TestUser(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(email="naveen@example.com",name="Naveen",contact_number="9090909098",gender="0",address="jaipur",state="Rajasthan",city="Jaipur",country="India",pincode="302016",dob="1907-07-20",is_active="True", is_admin= "False")

    def test_get_User(self):    
        response = self.client.get(reverse('customer_info_view'))
        ...
    
    def test_post_User(self):
        data = {
            ...
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('customer_info_view'), data=data)
        ...
 
    def test_update_user(self):
        pk = self.user.id
        data = {
            "email":"naveen@example.com",
        
        }

        response = self.client.patch(reverse('customer_info_detail_view', kwargs={
            'pk': pk,
        }), data, content_type='application/json')

        result = response.json()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # self.assertEqual(result["email"], "ujjval@example.com")
```

Comment: Getting the same error.

Comment: I think the `pk` might not be the one of the created user. So I set the created user as the member of the class in the `setUp` function and changed the code of `test_update_user` function. Please check it again.